# Redirect old domain to new domain with htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Need to migrate from example.com to example.net. 
The following .htaccess working well to do this.

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.net/$1 [L,R=301]`

Additionally, I need the request to the home page of example.com/ to redirect to example.net/home and NOT to example.net/ ,  as it is done in the above code.

Appreciate suggestions on how to do this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need 2 separate rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

# home page
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://example.net/home [L,R=301]

# rest of the pages
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ http://example.net/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1):

There's absolutely no need for mod_rewrite if you're doing a simple 1:1 redirect:

```
<virtualhost ...>
    ServerName example.com
    Redirect permanent / http://example.net
</virtualhost>
```

This'll even take care of "sub urls". `example.com/foo/bar` -> `example.net/foo/bar`.